# PHP Convert a Date into this format

Tags: php, datetime, date

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP convert one date into another date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167916/php-convert-one-date-into-another-date-format)

This is PHP

I have this result:

```
2011-09-20 13:00:00
```

I want to convert it into this format:

```
September 20 2011 1:00 pm
```

Do you know how to do that?

Anyhelp would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
$old_date = '2011-09-20 13:00:00';
$old_date_timestamp = strtotime($old_date);
$new_date = date('F j Y g:i a', $old_date_timestamp);
```

Answer (score 2):

If that result comes from an object of type DateTime you can use the [format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) function:

```
$date = new DateTime('2000-01-01');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

and [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) all the formats you can have.. change it according to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the UNIX-timestamp of a time string with `strtotime()` and you can get a differently designed time string with `strftime()`

Answer (score 1):

For more information you can read the documentation here : http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

But also is simple. Lets see how

```
$d = "2011-09-20 13:00:00";
$d = strtotime($d);
$d = date("F m Y g:i a", $d);
echo $d;
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at these PHP functions:

http://nl.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

and

http://nl.php.net/strtotime

To do something like this:

```
date('F d Y G:i',strtotime("2011-09-20 13:00:00")); // your required format
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this format

```
$date= date("F j Y g:i a");
```

if you have date in any variable then

```
$date= date("F j Y g:i a",strtotime($your_variable));

echo $date
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo date("F d Y g:i a",strtotime("2011-09-20 13:00:00 "));
```

Answer (score 1):

`echo date('F d Y g:i a', strtotime('2011-09-20 13:00:00'));`

check the [date format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)